# Restoring 2.79 click functionality in Blender 2.8 particularly with respect to lasso select

Tags: customization, selection-tools

I am really used to using the lasso selected in Blender 2.79, but for some reason I cannot seem to figure out how to get similar functionality out of Blender 2.8.

Note that I have the "Keymap" option set to "Blender 27X".

My particular issues are:

- When I have the lasso select selected in the toolbar and ctrl+click, Blender refuses to select anything.
- Under certain circumstances, Blender changes the lasso select mode back to box select mode. I have tried to debug what these circumstances are but cannot figure it out. It seems related either to switching modes (e.g. from Edit to Object) or maybe to switching tools (which I avoid, as I never want a tool selected other than 3D cursor).

Essentially what I'm trying to recreate is the Blender 2.79 controls of left-click for 3D cursor, ctrl+click for lasso select, and right-click for select. If there's just an option somewhere to do this that would be the best solution.

Otherwise what I've been doing is changing the select tool to the lasso select, and then trying to leave the tool selection on the 3D cursor tool. This however is not sufficient due to the issues listed above. In order for this to work for me I need to know how to prevent Blender from switching my tools without me clicking on them.

There are some promising looking options under the Keymap options but I'm afraid I cannot decipher what exactly they all mean, although I've looked at [this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/keymap_editing.html#keymap-customize).

I've been searching for solutions to this for a few months now and have not found any. Perhaps my google-fu is not strong enough but I figure it would make sense to ask here at this point.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: In Blender 2.8x you can hold Shift to extend the selection or Ctrl to remove parts of the selection with the lasso select tool.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I am aware of those features; as I said, I use the lasso select a lot. :) My problem is more that, for example, if you open a new Blender 2.8 file, ctrl+click does not lasso select, while in Blender 2.7 it would. Thanks anyways.